# ion-select doesn't render selected value when filtered data used

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I encountered strange bug with ion-select dynamic data filtering. In my application user should choose three security question during registration, so this questions cannot be the same. I have array of questions:

```
 questions: Array<{isSelected: boolean;question: string}> = [
    {isSelected: false, question: 'What is your pet’s name?'},
    {isSelected: false, question: 'What is the first name of the person you first kissed?'},
    {isSelected: false, question: 'Who was your childhood hero?'},
    {isSelected: false, question: 'What was your first grade friend last name?'},
    {isSelected: false, question: 'Where did you celebrate your 20th birthday?'},
    {isSelected: false, question: 'In what city or town does your nearest sibling live?'},
    {isSelected: false, question: 'What time of the day were you born?'}];
```

This part of my registration form looks like this:

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Select security question*</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="regModel.SecurityQuestions[i].Question" name="Question"
                  [selectOptions]="sqSelectOptions"
                  (ionChange)="chooseQuestion(regModel.SecurityQuestions[i].Question)">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let sqOption of questions|filterSQ" value="{{sqOption.question}}"> {{sqOption.question}}
        </ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Your answer*</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" required [(ngModel)]="regModel.SecurityQuestions[i].Answer" name="Answer"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

  </div>
```

I use `(ionChange)="chooseQuestion(regModel.SecurityQuestions[i].Question)` to track selected options:

```
 chooseQuestion(s: string) {
    console.log(this.TAG + 'chooseQuestion: event value: ' + s);
    this.questions.filter(res => res.question == s).map(res => res.isSelected = true);
    //todo rewrite this 
    this.questions.filter(res => res.isSelected == true &&
    res.question != this.regModel.SecurityQuestions[0].Question &&
    res.question != this.regModel.SecurityQuestions[1].Question &&
    res.question != this.regModel.SecurityQuestions[2].Question)
      .map(res => res.isSelected = false);
    this.questions_filtered = this.questions.filter(res => res.isSelected == false);

    console.log(this.TAG + 'chooseQuestion: questions: ' + JSON.stringify(this.questions));
    console.log(this.TAG + 'chooseQuestion: questions_filtered: ' + JSON.stringify(this.questions_filtered));
  }
```

According to logs logic works fine. For the first time i used questions_filtered to provide questions for ion-select, and encountered problem: **selected option doesn't display in UI field.**  Then I tried to use pipes as recommended way to filter data, same effect. 
I will appreciate any advice. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

To clarify the case I added some record and rewrote code a little bit. Two of three questions in this example have pipes and last one doesn't. I get correct values but without actual displaying.

[image]

**Update**

I still don't know why solution proposed by **@misha130** didn't give any result. So I tried to dig around with Chrome inspector, and found out that this part wasn't called.(I copied highlighted part but I'm not sure was it correct) http://plnkr.co/edit/n4wv2UUdLtCmt4enYuVS?p=catalogue

Comment: What is the UI Field? The ion-select itself? I imagine it happens because you are inside an array and the change detection doesn't apply to arrays so you must apply detect changes on your own. Also might aswell use  (ionChange)="chooseQuestion($event)" instead of what you are using

Comment: @misha130 hi, I have changed already ionChange to use events, thank you. Could you clarify please how can I apply detect changes? I also updated my question with some demonstration of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Angular2 doesn't detect changes in arrays and its children objects. For this to actual take effect in your view you'll have to call a change detection

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

// Inject to constructor
constructor(public cd:ChangeDetectorRef){}

// as per your example call it on in your ionChange method
chooseQuestion(s: string) {
  this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

For more information: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: Nice article, thank you. But unfortunately it didn't work.